# Jquery click event was not working

Tags: jquery, css

In my web page i used click event for a dropdown tab.But the code was not working for me. 
But If i use hover instead of click event it works well.But i need to use click in my web page code is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                var dropDownSpeed = 200;
                var dropUpSpeed   = 200;
                var menuHeight = '240px';
                var tabs = $("#tabs");
                var tabPanesContainer = $("ul#tabPanes");
                var tabPanesAll = tabPanesContainer.find("li").css("position", "absolute");

                $(".slide").click(function () {

                    var thisMenuItem = $(this);

                    /*get the offset of this item in respect to the page*/
                    var thisMargin   = thisMenuItem.offset().center;

                    /*get the offset of the navigation bar in respect to the page*/
                    var tabsOffset   = tabs.offset().center;
                    var thisIndex = thisMenuItem.index();

                    thisMargin = Math.floor(thisMargin - tabsOffset);


                    var thisOffset = thisMargin - 52;

                    /* handle IE margin difference*/
                    if($.browser.msie)
                    {
                      thisOffset = thisMargin - 15;
                    }


                    tabPanesContainer.css('margin-left', thisOffset);

                    tabPanesContainer.stop().animate({
                        height: menuHeight
                    }, dropDownSpeed);



                    tabMenuLinks.removeClass('activeTab');
                    thisMenuItem.addClass('activeTab');


                    var thisHash = thisMenuItem.find("a").attr('href');
                    var tabClicked = tabPanesAll.filter(thisHash);


                    tabClicked.appendTo(tabPanesContainer).show();



                    return false;


                }, function() {

                   $(this).stop();

                });
                });
            });
```

Please help me to solve the problem Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You have the `wrong syntax for the click event` ..

It takes in only one function handler and not two as you have written

```
 $(".slide").click(function () {

     // Click event code
 }, function() {
              $(this).stop();

});
```

It **works for hover event** as it can take two handler functions..

For the click event to work your signature has to be

```
$(".slide").click(function () {

         // Click event code
});

// Remove the other function
```

Comment: My need is if the user clicks on "<li class="dropdown"><a href="#tab1" class="slide">Forgot Password</a></li>" link then a drop down tab must appear below the link

Answer (score 0):

Technically you shouldn't be passing a secondary callback, what's happening is your:

```
$(this).stop();
```

Is firing before all of your other code. The javascript is ignoring your first callback function you specified since .click is only supposed to accept on callback method. I'm curious what is your .stop() even being used for? I'm not totally sure but I don't really think you need that at all.

One other piece of advice is to use the .on() method instead of click. The .click() method has been deprecated so instead of what you have use something like this:

```
$(".slide").on('click', function () {
    // Click event code
});
```

What you're doing with .click() is just making a call to this .on() anyways plus using .on() is much more extendable meaning now you could bind multiple events to listen for so for instance you could do this:

```
$(".slide").on('click, mouseover, mouseenter', function () {
    // Click event code
});
```

Comment: I removed $(this).stop; And If i use the above method also problem remains same.